# Modular residue number theory problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given large enough integer $N$ is there always $(\lceil\log N\rceil)^d$ pairs of integers $z,p$ where each of $p$ is distinct prime with $N<p$ and $z$ satisfies $z\bmod p<\frac{zN\bmod p}{N}$ where $d\geq1$ are fixed?

In general how do we find $(\lceil\log N\rceil)^d$ such pairs?

Assume we have the Riemann hypothesis and the Cramer's conjecture.

Comment: what ? rearrange your statement, it is impossible to understand. given $N$, then given $d$ arbitrary large, ....

Comment: @user1952009 '..large enough' .. 'fixed?'.

Comment: it is impossible to understand. rewrite everything